# Viewing a protected folder using php

Tags: php

I am trying to allow users access to a protected folder using php. For example the downloads folder **https://xxxxx/downloads**

The folder has been set as protected using `cPanel` and a user created with a password. If I try access the folder directly it prompts for the username and password (see pic), and then the contents of the folder are displayed.

[image]

However I am trying to do this programmatically, without the Windows Security dialog box coming up, and giving me more control of what is being viewed and allowing me to programmatically log users out too.

I have tried to find information on this but have drawn a blank. Any pointers?

Comment: So... you're trying to create a regular login system?

Comment: No - the folder is protected using cPanel. I am wondering how you can access this folder without using the Windows Security log in. ie. How do I use php to access the username and password settings set by cPanel for authentication?

Comment: It shows that you are on IIS and not on Apache. May you check the IIS version?

Comment: So... you're trying to access the site programmatically from somewhere else using PHP? E.g. `file_get_contents('http://example.com/protected/folder')`?

Comment: I suspect you will either have to adjust the `AUTH` type for windows from Basic to Form or use `curl`. You will need some sort of login form - like @deceze mentioned, but you will then authenticate against IIS site users and not a database. I suspect you will run into the regular issues that all Windows app developers do, and overcome them somehow or move to a MySQL DB authentication method. There are a lot of problems with Basic authentication like this and my pointer would be to not use it.